# retrieving the multivalued array from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have trouble getting the facet in my index.
Basically I want to get the details  of particular facet say "Company" in a separate array

I tried many queries but it all get entire facet under facet array .How can I get only particular facet in a facet array

My index is https://gist.github.com/4015817

Please help me .I am badly stuck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering how complex your data structure is, the simples way to extract this information might be using [script fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/script-fields.html):

```
curl "localhost:9200/index/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {

        }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "entity_facets": {
            "script": "result=[];foreach(facet : _source.Categories.Types.Facets) {if(facet.entity==entity) result.add(facet);} result",
            "params": {
                "entity": "Country"
            }

        },
        "first_facet": {
            "script": "_source.Categories.Types.Facets[0]"    
        }

    }
}'
```

Comment: thanks alot imotov. You helped me from a great trouble. Thanks very much .